# Объясните пожалуйста эти строки,что откуда и к чему?

Tags: opencart

```
{% set config = registry.get('config') %}
{% set language_id = config.get('config_language_id') %}
{% set boss_category = config.get('boss_category') %}
{% set text_save_off = config.get('theme_' ~ config.get('config_theme') ~ '_text_save_off') %}
{% set text_save_off = text_save_off[language_id] is defined ? 
text_save_off[language_id] : '' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**{% set variable = value %}** - инициализация переменной и присвоение ей значения в шаблоне twig

**registry.get('config')** - какой-то самописный (разработчиками темы или расширения) реестр